# How to fix order of cells in uicollectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have viewController with collectionView - 15 cells, all of one type. Inside cell is a button with number in title, or padlock(locked chapter). When I first load this view, all is ok and the cells are in right order (1-15). When I click on the button, new view with chapter opens. When I return to previous view from currently finished chapter, I need to unlock next (change its title to number, dismiss picture of padlock and enable user interactions). I call this function:

```
func updateButtons() {
        for i in 0..<chapterCollectionView.visibleCells.count {
            if let cell = chapterCollectionView.visibleCells[i] as? ExampleCollectionViewCell {
                if i <= PLAYERS[ACTUAL_PLAYER].progress {
                    cell.button.setTitle(String(i + 1), for: .normal)
                    cell.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    cell.button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
                } else {
                    cell.button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                    cell.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    if self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular && self.view.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
                        cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "padlock1"), for: .normal)
                    } else {
                        cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "padlock"), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I try, all buttons change their positions randomly. Is there a way to fix their order. Picture links are in comment.

Comment: links to pictures: https://imgur.com/bAlYtv6 , https://imgur.com/hIVU4Ks

Comment: You reload the collectionview, that's better, because cells are reused.

Comment: reload using reloadData()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reloadData()` works in cooperation with `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` function. Thanks Larme